# Bluemix SQL Database Small Plan Cost

Tags: ibm-cloud

I see documentation in Bluemix SQL database service stating a small plan; however I do not see it as a option when selecting the service.  Is it still an option?  If so what are the details of the plan?

Comment: Not really a programming question and probably off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) (filtering the updates), the SQL Database small plan has been discontinued. The following is the full announcement:

> Starting September 1, 2015, new SQL Database small instances cannot be added. To improve our SQL Database services, new service architecture will deliver better scalability and security options. As a result, we will sunset the SQL Database Small Plan in favor of our SQL Database Free, SQL Database Premium, Compose PostgreSQL plans.

Answer (score 0):

The small plan for SQLDB is not offered anymore. It was withdrawn earlier this year (2015). So no details are available...

I found the small plan used for one example in the documentation and submitted feedback on that. Expect that to be gone soon.